# Why does my javafx stage not want to load

Tags: java, javafx

This is the java

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class mains extends Stage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JFXPanel();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new mains();
        }

    });
}
void go(){
    new JFXPanel();
    new mains().show();
}

public mains() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
            "LOL.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@FXML
private Button button;

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
void push(ActionEvent event) {

}

}
```

here is the fxml http://pastebin.com/uzBrMRDV
I get a load exception it says Root is already specified.
If i remove the setRoot(this); it doesnt load at all
I am getting really frustrated with JFX...
Is there anyway to load FXML files like a Stage from the controller itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the line

`fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);`

Your FXML defines the root to be an `AnchorPane` (and you can't set the root twice, which is why you are getting the error).

Since the current class is a `Stage`, and the `FXMLLoader` loads an `AnchorPane`, you need to put the loaded `AnchorPane` in a `Scene` and set the scene in the stage. Replace

```
fxmlLoader.load();
```

with

```
AnchorPane root = fxmlLoader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root); // optionally specify dimensions too
this.setScene(scene);
```